# CSS Unordered List Long Text Display Inline

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an unordered list that displays like this: http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/XYBja/.

Notice how the second list item is too long, so it wraps onto another line, beneath the first list item. Is there a way to keep each list item within its own "column" without assigning explicit widths?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is there any special reason as to why you're using this kind of structure? Are there going to be several of these joined together? If so, how are you planning on showing any subsequent item - below? Next to? The posted solutions will work fine in many cases, but if your list is supposed to follow a certain model it might be a bit tricky to achieve (with nice results) without properly setting the width on at least the image or its container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this on you css

```
img{
  float:left;
}
```

this should do the trick =)

Comment: Thank you, your trick worked! I added a few enhancements, as well to clear the floats: http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/XYBja/6/

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `li img {float: left`} because that will float your image to left and I think that should solve your problem!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, your trick worked! I added a few enhancements, as well to clear the floats: http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/XYBja/6/

Comment: You're welcome! I have answered first, but no worries...the main thing is that both were helpful! :)